# How do I know if a stored procedure is in use?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database

I have a ASP.NET MVC 4 website bound to a MS SQL Server database. I can see among the many `aspnet_` stored procedures some custom ones.

How do I know if these custom stored procedure are in use? Should I check the C# code or something else?

Thanks.

Comment: Custom stored procedures shouldn't have the `aspnet_` prefix

Comment: Why do you need to know which one is used? Do you want to migrate to other type of database? link how to obtain information about used SP on production for example https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3259/several-methods-to-collect-sql-server-stored-procedure-execution-history/

Answer (score 1):

In Object Explorer, right click the stored procedure -> View Dependencies.

Also, search through the c# code after the name of the stored procedure.

Comment: the OP should totally do that but it won't help him if any other client is using that database.

Comment: Sure, I guess the combination of our answers would be the best.

Comment: They all depend only on their self...

Comment: Ok, so then you know that no other stored procedure or other database object is using it. What's left is to search through your server code.

Comment: Bear in mind if you use Entity Framework (which you haven't stated but is common), this won't show as a dependency in SSMS as its your code base that utilises it.

Answer (score 0):

if you have the relevant SQL permissions, you could just run

```
SELECT 
    DB_NAME(database_id),
    OBJECT_NAME(object_id),
    cached_time,
    last_execution_time,
    execution_count
FROM 
    sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats;
```

That'll tell you the last time each stored procedure was run *on the instance you're querying*.

Other than this, I don't think there is a way. The cache stores execution plans to some extent but they get enormous and are by default truncated in storage.  And stored procedures can be configured to run without an execution plan anyway, especially the groovy new compiled stored procedures.

Searching the C# will almost certainly not help you unless you're certain that your code is the only client.